# Is DWR (Direct Web Remoting) Secure?

Tags: javascript, java

Is DWR considered secure, or what may be required to secure Direct Web Remoting?

Are there better options for hardened asynchronous communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DWR is [reasonably secure](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/documentation/security/index.html) if you use it securely. Anything can by made insecure through usage. You still need to validate all your inputs.